# birthday problem help

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

For the birthday problem, how many people are needed to ensure that at least three people are born in the same month?

After looking at the problem I think the answer would be 25 because

12 + 12 + 1?

Answer (score 2):

You have it.  You can avoid three in a month with 24, 2 in each month, but not with one more.